# Accessing node server through url

Tags: node.js

So I have this script

```
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 2525;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

File named nodeTest.js and I have all this on a webhost where I also have my domain. Now running this script through ssh "node nodeTest.js" creates server and I can access it with another ssh terminal with curl call. I get response "hello world" as I should.

Now the problem is I cannot access it normally through my domain link.. like somethingsomething.com

I also have option to create node application through a cpanel but when I create it i get no response going to specified link
[image]

I just started with nodejs so maybe I am missing something obvious. There is also help site on my webhost web that has tutorial how to set this up and I do as they say but i get no console.log msg.
[image]

I also tried setting server to 8080 port but I get error already in use.

Would appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure how your hosting works, but usually when you want to expose something out of the server you would use `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. So I would try with changing the first line to `const hostname = '0.0.0.0;`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. with the help of this site
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-software/create-application-with-nodejs-selector

I was missing package.json part